# Monkeypatch an executable in Python pytest

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, pytest

In Python 3.10, I have a function like:

```py
from shutil import which
def my_func():
    if which('myexecutable.sh'):
       # do stuff
    else:
       # do other stuff
```

I would like to write a unit test with Pytest that runs the first part code even though the executable is not present. What is the best way to do this?

I know that I can use `monkeypatch.setenv()` to set an environment variable, but that's not going to make the `which()` check pass. There's also the added challenge of making sure this is compatible on Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 1):

You could try like this:

```py
# in script file
from shutil import which

def myfunc():
    if which("myexecutable.sh"):
        return "OK"
    else:
        ...
```

```py
# in test file
import pytest
from script import myfunc


@pytest.fixture
def which(mocker):
    return mocker.patch("script.which", autospec=True)


def test_myfunc(which):
    assert myfunc() == "OK"
```

Running **pytest** outputs: `1 passed`

Comment: Now this is a neat trick!